# Select date individually from list of dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetData]  
    @startdate DATE 
AS
    WITH dates(Date) AS   
    (  
        SELECT @startdate AS Date  
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT DATEADD (d, 1, [Date])  
        FROM dates   
        WHERE DATE < GETDATE()  
    )  
    SELECT Date  
    FROM dates  
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)  
GO
```

it returns a list of dates

```
exec spGetData @startdate = '2019/11/28'
```

Output:

```
Date  
----------
2019-11-28  
2019-11-29  
2019-11-30  
2019-12-01  
2019-12-02  
2019-12-03
```

How do I select each date individually in the same stored procedure as I want to pass date as parameter in another stored procedure?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But it sounds like you want to do some looping. I would urge you to rethink that requirement and consider passing a table valued parameter instead.

Comment: yes, I want to loop through date and select individual dates and pass it as a parameter to another sp

Comment: Again...you should reconsider this approach. Looping is horribly inefficient. Passing a table valued parameter would be a much better approach.

Comment: can you please give an example to explain as im just a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is ditch all the current code and put a WHILE loop that starts with the current date and increments it with DATEADD each time.

I'm presuming you have a reason that the other SP needs to be called separately for each date.

Comment: Ugh...ditch all the current set based logic and go with RBAR (row by agonizing row). I understand that the OP is new but yikes....loops should be avoided whenever possible. The solution by Pranav is a much better way to handle this. You might also have to adjust the stored procedure on the other end to deal with sets though which can sometime be a deal breaker.

Comment: The solution by Pranav is a good solution to a different problem. The OP asked to call the SP separately for each date. There is no set-based solution for that. And I might add, it's not correct as written either, as TVPs must be flagged as READONLY in the proc headers. But it's not a solution to the given problem. As I said in my answer "I'm presuming you have a reason that the other SP needs to be called separately for each date". As an example, people often need to call SPs that they didn't write and they need to call. Given the requirement, that's the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

First define a table type like :

```
CREATE TYPE UT_Date AS TABLE  
    (
     startdate date
    )
```

You can use this to pass multiple records in Stored procedure as parameter like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_OtherSP(@Dates [UT_Date])  
AS  
BEGIN 

--you can access table valued parameter data just like a table 
SELECT * FROM @Dates
-- your logic here

END
```